# Related entries in a Safecracker form?

Tags: expressionengine, safecracker

I'm trying to create a Safecracker form in ExpressionEngine to create a recipe. I have a recipe channel, which can have many ingredients from an ingredients channel (using the multi-relationship add-on from devot:ee). However, I'm having trouble listing the ingredients within my form. This is my mark-up:

```
{exp:safecracker channel='recipes' datepicker='no' id='add-recipe-form' include_jquery='no' return='recipes/view/ENTRY_ID' safecracker_head='no'}
    {related_entries id='ingredients'}
        {title}
    {/related_entries}
{/exp:safecracker}
```

The problem is, the actual EE tags are just getting output on my web page.

I figure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, so could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "variable collision" - you're nesting entries which use the same variable/tag names as those used by the parent tag (in this case, `{title}`), and due to how EE's [parse order](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Parse_Order) works, the parent tag is winning every time.

The solution is to put your above code into another template, and [embed that template](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/embedding.html) within your Safecracker form. Embeds are run at the very end of template processing, after all of the other EE tags are parsed, so you won't run into the same collision.

Comment: Thanks, Derek. This will be good to know for future development!

Answer (score 0):

Derek is right, you need to embed your related entries. I've got this working on my Toronto EE meetup site with this code.

Simplified Template code:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="gta-attendee"}
<div class="form_row" style="display:none;">
<label class="small">Choose Meetup to Attend:<span class="required">*</span></label>
{embed="includes/_playa_select" selected="{attendee-event:child_ids}" }
</div>
{/exp:safecracker}
```

embedded code:

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" channel="gta-meetup" limit="1"}
<input value="{entry_id}" name="attendee-event[selections][]" type="hidden">
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

In the code I'm using the Playa Module, but the principle is the same.
Hope this helps

Sean